# Android YouTube Player API

Tags: java, android

I want to play you-tube video inside my app as small one as you-tube playing...could any one guide me please...I tried wit YouTube video player but it get stuck or stop after every second.

Trying to find out some solutions for this but not getting it.I need small view to play you-tube video same as you-tube in android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give internet permission on manifests then intent the activity to browser